# Git Parameter Alias not working

Tags: git, alias, git-branch, branching-and-merging

So I am trying to create an alias for something I do in Git all the time: create a new branch based on my develop branch but that doesnt track it.  The code I type into the command prompt to do this is:

```
Git checkout –b branchname --no-track origin/develop
```

Now, I want to turn that into an alias, so I am trying this:

```
git config --global alias.newBranch "!git checkout -b $1 --no-track origin/develop"
```

However, when I type in "git newBranch test", I get back this: "fatal: 'test' is not a commit and a branch 'test' cannot be created from it"

What am I missing here?

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer below, lots of good information on the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git interprets aliases literally. I.e., when expanding an alias git just
does simple textual substitution. In your case if you run `git newBranch test` git expands that to the command

```
!git checkout -b $1 --no-track origin/develop test
```

which is certainly not what you want. You need a shell function to pass parameters:

```
git config --global alias.newBranch "!f() { git checkout -b $1 --no-track origin/develop; }; f"
```

Comment: Aliases can still help. `git config --global alias.cont checkout --no-track` will be useful, and can make this solution shorter: `git config --global alias.newBranch "!f() { git cont -b $1 origin/develop } f"`

Comment: My answer didn't really add anything other than an alternate form, so I'll add it as a comment instead. You can also call bash directly rather than defining a function `git config --global alias.newBranch '!bash -c "git checkout -b $1 --no-track origin/develop" -'` especially useful if you're ever calling a shell script to avoid scoping issues